# Aligning Parts Horizontally

Tags: enumerate, exam, parts

I am working on an exercise sheet using the Exam class and I want to achieve the following using parts:

[image]

Can anyone here help me?

I tried using the Multicolumn environment however it produces the parts in the incorrect order

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! what is the problem? to retype presented image in questions? please show us what you try so far.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365126/how-to-align-first-line-in-an-array. it may help you.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595360/87678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a task for `tasks`. (As Zarko is saying not many are eager to type in texts from a screen shot.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\settasks{counter-format=(tsk[a]),label-width=1.5em}
\begin{enumerate}
\item    Which one of the following statements are true?
    \begin{tasks}(3)
        \task \dots
        \task \dots
        \task \dots
        \task \dots
        \task \dots
        \task \dots
    \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]